# Create or update a Django Model based on ID field

Tags: django

I'm trying to use the same form to create or update a Django model. Unfortunately, the `update_or_create()` method suggested in other answers does not work if the identifier is `None`. Currently, I'm checking if the `id` is `None`, getting a `ModelForm` and then creating or updating the object as needed in separate code flows.

Here is my code:

```
# When the Conquest already exists
if c_id is not None:
    # Check if Conquest is valid, else throw error
    conq = get_object_or_404(Conquest,id=c_id)

    # Verify ModelForm data based on existing instance
    form = ConquestForm(request.POST,instance=conq)
    if not form.is_valid():
        print form.errors
        return json_response(messages='Invalid form data')

    conq.title=form.cleaned_data['title']
    conq.description=form.cleaned_data['description']
    conq.start_time=form.cleaned_data['start_time']
    conq.end_time=form.cleaned_data['end_time']
    conq.save()
    return JsonResponse({'success':'true','message':'Conquest updated'},status=200)

else:
    # Verify ModelForm data based
    form = ConquestForm(request.POST)    
    if not form.is_valid():
        print form.errors
        return json_response(messages='Invalid form data')

    conq = Conquest.objects.create(
            title=form.cleaned_data['title'], 
            description=form.cleaned_data['description'],
            start_time=form.cleaned_data['start_time'],
            end_time=form.cleaned_data['end_time'])

    return JsonResponse({'success':'true','message':'Conquest created'},status=200)
```

How can I avoid the code duplication:

1. In creating the `form` object with/without the `instance` specified
2. In having separate code for creating and updating while the id is `null`

If I do not specify `instance=conq` , I receive an integrity error as the `title` must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you need to know first. When you are using a `ModelForm`, you don't manually create/update instances. You do create/update when you call `form.save()`.

If you provide a `None` to the instance parameter to the form, it will actually treat current form as a creation form, otherwise it treats it form as an update form on object for parameter `instance`.

If you use form to automatically handle these, you won't have the `IntegrityError` because form would be invalid and the error would be in `form.errors`, you could easily return that to the client for notification.

Here's the rough implementation, it might not work out of the box, but at least it should be enough to guide you what you need to do:

```
def func(request, c_id):
    if c_id:
        conq = get_object_or_404(Conquest, id=c_id)
    else:
        conq = None

    form = ConquestForm(request.POST or None, instance=conq)
    if form.is_valid():
        # this could either be a creation or an update
        conquest = form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'success': true})
    else:
        errors = form.errors
        return JsonReponse({'success':false, 'errors': errors})
```

Django doc about [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).